# Worklight - Connect Trigger In Wifi Is Throwing An Error

Tags: android, triggers, wifi, ibm-mobilefirst, android-geofence

function

```
loadWifiTracking() {

      var policy = {

            Wifi: {
                interval: 3000,
                signalStrengthThreshold: 15,
                accessPointFilters: [{SSID:"wifiName"}]
            }
      };

      var triggers = {

        Wifi: {

            DwellInSide: {
                type: "DwellInside",
                areaAccessPoints: [{SSID: 'wifiName'}],
                callback:function() {alert("Thank You For Being Here!");},
                dwellingTime: 5000
            },

            Connected: {
                type: 'Connect',
                connectedAccessPoint:[{SSID: 'wifiName'}],
                callback: function() {alert("Reached Here");}
            },

        }

      };


     WL.Device.startAcquisition(policy, triggers, acquisitionFailure);

         var acquisitionFailure = {

             Wifi : wifiFailure,

     };

     function wifiFailure(positionError) {

        alert("pe" + positionError);

     }

}
```

It's throwing an error:

`The WIFI Connect trigger with  network specification: [{"SSID":"wifiName"}] will have no affect, since this network do not appear in WIFI acquisition policy.`

Any Idea what is the exact problem? Please do help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Connected: {
                type: 'Connect',
                connectedAccessPoint:[{SSID: 'wifiName'}],
                callback: function() {alert("Reached Here");}
            },
```

As you can see in the case of the `Connect` triggers, the property `connectedAccessPoint`, is singular. Therefore you should not pass an array of SSIDs, but rather a single SSID.

Try:

```
Connected: {
                    type: 'Connect',
                    connectedAccessPoint:{SSID: 'wifiName'},
                    callback: function() {alert("Reached Here");}
                },
```